Dropdown in ListView
I have a ListView that contains this dropdown. Items of the dropdown are shown, it's from API, but it throws an error when I select the value

Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value

'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 888 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'"

I guess it's throwing that error because of a duplicate dropdown in the ListView that uses the same item. I think it should use an index for different dropdowns. Any suggestions for code examples, please?
List? answerList;

This is the function to fetch data:
void answerSetupDropdown() async {
    var headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
    var request =
        http.Request('POST', Uri.parse(baseLaravelAPI + '/api/start_section'));
    request.body = json.encode({
      "staffid": widget.staffId.toString(),
      "form_open_id": widget.formOpenId.toString(),
      "section_id": widget.sectionId.toString(),
      "form_id": widget.formId.toString(),
      "confirm_no": widget.confNo.toString()
    });
    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final res = jsonDecode(await response.stream.bytesToString());
      answerList = res["data"]["answer_list"];
      loading = false;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Unable to fetch products from the REST API');
    } 
    
  }

This is a dropdown that shows the item:
 ListView.builder(
                itemCount: chilList!.length,
                
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
loading == false
                                    ? Expanded(
                                        // alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                        child: Theme(
                                          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                                            unselectedWidgetColor: lightblue,
                                          ),
                                          child: DropdownButton<dynamic>(
                                            underline: SizedBox(),
                                            hint: Text("Select Answer"),
                                            value: selectedValue,
                                            onChanged: (dynamic value) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                selectedValue =
                                                    (value["answer_name"])
                                                        .toString();
                                              });
                                              // selectedValue =
                                              //     (valueSel["answer_name"])
                                              //         .toString();
                                            },
                                            items: answerList!.map((answer) {
                                              return DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>(
                                                value: answer,
                                                child: Row(
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    SizedBox(
                                                      width: 10,
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      answer["answer_name"]
                                                          .toString(),
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Color(
                                                              int.parse((answer[
                                                                      "answer_color"])
                                                                  .replaceAll(
                                                                      RegExp(
                                                                          '#'),
                                                                      '0xFF')))),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            }).toList(),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    : CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  });


Ensure that the selectedValue is unique for each item

That means your answerList variable has 2 identical values. Because DropdownMenuItem value must be unique.
In example:
Bad
List answerList = [1,2,3,3];


It's bad because answer has two 3 (not unique), it will confusing DropdownButton

Good
List answerList = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9];


It's good because all value in the list is unique. So DropdownButton can identify which one is selected by your value

Code Example
DropdownButton(
  items: answerList.map(
    (answer) => DropdownMenuItem(
      // So when you iterate this dropdownmenuitem, make sure
      // this [value] is unique, no duplicated [answer].
      value: answer,
      child: Text('$answer'),
    ),
  ),
  onChanged: onChanged,
)

